# How to use xsl:copy-of to get all nodes except one under a particular element?

Tags: xml, xslt

**input xml:**

```
<ce:author-group xmlns:ce="http://tempuri.org/ce" xmlns:sa="http://tempuri.org/sa">
  <ce:author>
    <ce:given-name>Rafael</ce:given-name>
    <ce:surname>Torres</ce:surname>
    <orfid>a</orfid>
    <ce:e-address type="email">rtorres@sissa.it</ce:e-address>
  </ce:author>
  <ce:affiliation>
    <ce:label>a</ce:label>
    <sa:organization>Scuola Internazionale Superiori di Studi Avanzati, Via Bonomea 265, I-34136, Triest</sa:organization>
    <sa:country>Italy</sa:country>
  </ce:affiliation>
</ce:author-group>
```

**desired output xml:**

```
<ce:author-group xmlns:ce="http://tempuri.org/ce" xmlns:sa="http://tempuri.org/sa">
  <ce:affiliation>
    <ce:label>a</ce:label>
    <sa:organization>Scuola Internazionale Superiori di Studi Avanzati, Via Bonomea 265, I-34136, Trieste</sa:organization>
    <sa:country>Italy</sa:country>
  </ce:affiliation>
</ce:author-group>
```

how to use single `<xsl:copy-of select="...">` in xslt to get output xml?

I don't want the `author` information, I only want to get `affiliation` information.

Comment: you really meant to delete the whole `ce:author` node?

Answer (score 3):

> how to use single  in xslt to get output xml?

Not possible. `<xsl:copy-of>` makes a full, direct copy of the nodes you select. You cannot use it to make a partial copy.

What you need is the identity transformation with a single extra template:

```
<xsl:template match="ce:author" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with *just* a single `copy-of` because the output isn't a copy of any part of the input - it's a *new* `ce:author-group` element containing a copy of part of the input as its only child element.

The nearest you could get is

```
<xsl:template match="ce:author-group">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="ce:affiliation" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```